# Ubuntu LAMP stack - only index.php works

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I have installed a LAMP stack `apache2` on `Ubuntu 12.04`

I can access the Web Server over the LAN and can bring up pages like `index.php` (with working php in it) and `info.php` (which I created as part of the set up instructions and displays the php details) but I can't get any other html (gives a 404) or .php (display as blank) to work properly.

Comment: Where are you putting the .html files?

Comment: Please provide more information ? what are Apache's access log and error log are saying ?

Comment: in linux normally /var/www or /var/www/html will be the path where we need to put our files. Are you putting your files inside any of these paths?

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for looking at my post - have found the answer - permissions prob! used sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/my_site/ to fix it.  I'll add a full answer shortly.

Comment: Do a fresh install of your lamp host. You can refer below link how to configure it properly. https://www.wlpbasic.tech/how-to-configure-a-lamp-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

I looked in:
/var/log/apache2/error.log

I found:
'php fatal error unknown failed opening required'

which lead to an article that suggested the problem could be ownership/permissions so then I tried:

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/my_site/

Basically, I'd fiddled around with the folder ownership when trying to get the ftp to go outside of /home/user/
and that caused the problem.

To get around this use 'bind' to mount a folder outside home with an ftp folder inside home ftp strainght to your /var/www/my_site folder etc

do a search for:
"Allowing FTP Access to Files Outside the Home Directory Chroot" for the article, if you're interested.

However, since I did: chmod -R 755 /var/www/my_site/ although my site now works the ftp binding thing doesn't work but never mind - I need to do a bit of learning about the whole permissions thing!  Thanks for looking.